# Procedure for loading XML in oracle table using XMLType

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am inspired with a case of xml type procedure for parsing and insert data in a table here. In my case the table already exist and once the xml is generate by an external app i need load data in the table so i created my procedure and when i compiled all fine but at the execution i have mistakes.
So here is my procedure with xml inside.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dta_proc AS 
l_xml xmltype;
l_val VARCHAR2(10000) := '<root>
  <record>
  <id_localisation>8PJ</id_localisation>
  <data>
   <id_client>50C</id_client>  
      <mail>1@mail.com</mail>
      <adress>10  </adress>
      <num_tel>001</num_tel>
      <key>C</key>
     <contact>
        <name>toto</name>
        <birth>01/30/009</birth>
        <city>London</city>
      </contact>
  </data> 
  <data>
  <id_client>25C</id_client> 
      <mail>2@gmaiil.com</mail>
      <adress>20</adress>
      <num_tel>02200</num_tel>
      <key>D1</key>
      <contact>
        <name>tata</name>
        <birth>02/08/2004</birth>
        <city>Spa</city>
      </contact>
  </data> 
</record>
  <record>
  <id_localisation>ESP31</id_localisation>
  <data>
   <id_client>70D</id_client>  
        <mail>3@gmail.com</mail>
        <adress>7Bcd</adress>
        <num_tel>5555</num_tel>
        <key>D2</key>
      <contact>
        <name>titi</name>
        <birth>05/07/2014</birth>
        <city>StMarine</city>
      </contact>
  </data>
  <data>
        <id_client>10D</id_client>
        <mail>4@gmail.com</mail>
        <adress>888</adress>
        <num_tel>881.0</num_tel>
        <key>D3</key>
      <contact>
        <name>awk</name>
        <birth>05/08/1999</birth>
        <city>Bahrein</city>
      </contact>
  </data>
 </record>
 </root>';
     statut number;
     id_client varchar2(13);
     date_ev date;
     id_diff  varchar2(13);
BEGIN
     l_xml        := xmltype(l_val);

     FOR x IN
     (SELECT VALUE(p) col_val
     FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(l_xml, '/begin/entry'))) p
     )
     loop

IF x.col_val.existsnode('/root/record/id_localisation//text()') > 0 THEN
         localisation := x.col_val.extract('/root/record/id_localisation//text()').getstringval();
END IF;
if x.col_val.existsnode('/root/record/data/id_client/text()') > 0 then
     id_client := x.col_val.extract('/root/record/data/id_client/text()').getstringval();
end if;
if x.col_val.existsnode('/root/record/data/num_tel/text()') > 0 then
     num_tel := x.col_val.extract('/root/record/data/num_tel/text()').getstringval();
end if;
IF x.col_val.existsnode('/root/record/data/contact/city/text()') > 0 THEN
         city := x.col_val.extract('/root/record/data/contact/city/text()').getstringval();
end if;
INSERT INTO Customer
     (
          Loca,
          ID_CLT,
          TEL,
          Town
     )
     VALUES
     (
          localisation,
          id_client,
          num_tel,
          city
     );
     localisation := null;
     id_client := null;
     num_tel := null;
     city := null;
     end loop;
commit;
end  dta_proc;
```

Error when executing:

execute xml_procedure;

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00245: extra data after end of document
Error at line 26
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 310
ORA-06512: at "xml_procedure", line 58
ORA-06512: at line 1
31011. 00000 -  "XML parsing failed"
*Cause:    XML parser returned an error while trying to parse the document.
*Action:   Check if the document to be parsed is valid.
```

One more question. How is it possible to automate the loading of the xml in my procedure once it is generated?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what problems occur when you run the code. Provide some examples of what you think should happen, and then tell us what really happens. Thanks.

Comment: Are  you facing any errors while executing the procedure, if so please post them

Comment: i put the errors i got after execution of the script

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the xmlsequence etc to generate the xmltype, I would do something like the following (which works for me on 11.2.0.3):

```
with sample_data as (select 
'<root>
  <record>
    <id_localisation>8PJ</id_localisation>
    <data>
      <id_client>50C</id_client>  
      <mail>1@mail.com</mail>
      <adress>10  </adress>
      <num_tel>001</num_tel>
      <key>C</key>
      <contact>
        <name>toto</name>
        <birth>01/30/009</birth>
        <city>London</city>
      </contact>
    </data> 
    <data>
      <id_client>25C</id_client> 
      <mail>2@gmaiil.com</mail>
      <adress>20</adress>
      <num_tel>02200</num_tel>
      <key>D1</key>
      <contact>
        <name>tata</name>
        <birth>02/08/2004</birth>
        <city>Spa</city>
      </contact>
    </data> 
  </record>
  <record>
    <id_localisation>ESP31</id_localisation>
    <data>
      <id_client>70D</id_client>  
      <mail>3@gmail.com</mail>
      <adress>7Bcd</adress>
      <num_tel>5555</num_tel>
      <key>D2</key>
      <contact>
        <name>titi</name>
        <birth>05/07/2014</birth>
        <city>StMarine</city>
      </contact>
    </data>
    <data>
      <id_client>10D</id_client>
      <mail>4@gmail.com</mail>
      <adress>888</adress>
      <num_tel>881.0</num_tel>
      <key>D3</key>
      <contact>
        <name>awk</name>
        <birth>05/08/1999</birth>
        <city>Bahrein</city>
      </contact>
    </data>
  </record>
</root>' str from dual)
-- end of mimicking your sample xml
 select x.localisation,
        y.id_client,
        y.num_tel,
        y.city
 from   sample_data sd,
        xmltable('/root/record'
                 passing xmltype(sd.str)
                 columns localisation varchar2(20) path 'id_localisation',
                         subxml xmltype path '.') x,
        xmltable('/record/data'
                 passing x.subxml
                 columns id_client varchar2(13) path 'id_client',
                         num_tel varchar2(10) path 'num_tel',
                         city varchar2(20) path 'contact/city') y;

LOCALISATION         ID_CLIENT     NUM_TEL    CITY                
-------------------- ------------- ---------- --------------------
8PJ                  50C           001        London              
8PJ                  25C           02200      Spa                 
ESP31                70D           5555       StMarine            
ESP31                10D           881.0      Bahrein
```

You can then use that select statement in your insert (obviously, without the `WITH` clause, since you'd have your xml data stored somewhere (eg. a table or a parameter being passed in).

With regards to your question about automating the load of the xml once generated... you don't give us anywhere near enough information to be able to answer that. I would assume that the external application which generates the xml would want to call your procedure to store it, passing in the xml as a parameter.

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you do here, where is the declaration of  the procedure ? where is the insertion part ?

Comment: I have given you a select statement that takes the "xml" that you've provided and outputs the results. You can then plug that into an insert statement (you know about `INSERT INTO.... SELECT ...`, right?), which in turn you can plug into a procedure. Why don't you try doing this yourself - you'll learn more that way. If you get stuck, by all means edit your original question to add in what you've tried, and we can help further.